# Python, looping and get the first max value

Tags: python

Let's say I have this list containing these numbers: 1, 4, 8, 3, 5, 9, 2

I want to loop through this and get 8 because it's the first max value I encounter when loop through the list
I'm thinking of loop through each [i], and + the if statement:

`if [i] < [i+1] and [i+1] > [i+2]:`

`print(i)`

Although this print 8 which is what I want, it also prints 9 because it satisfied the condition. Is there a way to make it stop after printing 8?!

Comment: if you iterate over loop, you ll get 1 as max in first iteration. can you please little eloborate your question

Comment: `[i] < [i+1]` and `[i+1] > [i]` are equivalent, what's the point of checking the same thing twice? And what's the point of putting `i` and `i+1` into lists? And actually... that whole condition will *always* be true (for ints), so why check that at all?

Comment: I made a typo I edited the post

Comment: Check the solution provided where break can be used to stop iterating after its first encounter of max value

Comment: Even with a condition as vague as _"first max value"_, taken in pairs, the **first max is 4**, because 4 > 1. After that, 8 > 4. Then 9 > 5 or 9 > 8. What does "first max" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code you can try though to get the first max value between `i and i+1` index through the list

```py
nums = [1, 4, 8, 3, 5, 9, 2]
for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    if nums[i] > nums[i+1]:
        print(nums[i])
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `break` statement to break out of your loop. You can check out the use of `break`, `continue` and `pass` statements in Python here,

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/break-continue-and-pass-in-python/

The `break` statement is what is applicable to you here.

So, your code would look something like this,

```
for i in range(len(nums)-1):
  if [i] < [i+1]:
    print(i)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

By "first max", I'm assuming you mean the point where the immediate next element is lower?

Thats what I understood also going by your example -
Want `8` as the output out of `[1, 4, 8, 3, 5, 9, 2]`

If that is what you're looking for, you can try this -

```
a = [1, 4, 8, 3, 5, 9, 2]
for idx, val in enumerate(a):
    if val > a[idx+1]:
        # print(f"{idx} : {val}")
        print(val)
        break
```

I'm checking for the 1st occurrence where an element is higher than its very next element and breaking out of the loop at that point.